# Can I use auxiliary "be" for expressing period

Tags: present-perfect, past-perfect, auxiliary-verbs

I was in Canada for a year.

I am in Japan for two days.

I know present/past perfect sounds better but I'd like to know these are correct.

Comment: If this implies "staying" i guess they are both correct.

Answer (score 2):

They're correct - but be aware of the differences in meaning.

> I was in Canada for a year.

means that at some specified point in time, you have visited Canada, stayed there for a year, and then came back.

> I have been in Canada for a year.

means either the same thing (without necessarily specifying the point in time), *or* that you're still in Canada, and you've arrived a year ago.

> I had been in Canada for a year.

is a form you'd use when talking about the past - for example, you're relating a story from some years ago, and you want to say you *had been* in Canada for a year at that point.

> I am in Canada for a year.

means that you're still in Canada, but the year has not yet elapsed - instead, you *plan* to stay in Canada for a year.